# Частичный демаршалинг XML с пустым объектом c помощью JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

Имеется XML файл, который нужно распарсить строго с помощью JAXB. В файле у одного из объектов все поля пустые. Вылетает UnmarshalException. Как обработать это исключение, чтобы остальные валидные объекты остались? Пример XML:
`

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <books>
    <book id="1" category="Java">
        <title>Изучаем Java</title>
        <authors>
            <author>Кэти Сьерра</author>
            <author>Берт Бейтс</author>
        </authors>
        <description>Мировой компьютерный бестселлер</description>
    </book>
    <book id="2" category ="Алгоритмы">
        <title>Алгоритмы. Теория и практика</title>
        <authors>
            <author>Род Стивенс</author>
        </authors>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title></title>
        <authors>
            <author></author>
        </authors>
        <descritption></descritption>
    </book>
</books>
```

`
Класс-обёртка:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Books {

    private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Books() {
        super();
        for (Book b : bookList)
            if (b.isBookNull()) bookList.remove(b);
    }

    public void setBookList(List<Book> bookList) {
        this.bookList = bookList;
    }

    public boolean add(Book b) {
        return bookList.add(b);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "book")
    public List<Book> getBookList() {
        return bookList;
    }
}
```

Класс Book:

```
    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "book")
    public class Book {
        @XmlAttribute(required = true)
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
        @XmlID
        private String id;
        @XmlElement(name = "title")
        private String title = "";
        @XmlAttribute(required = false)
        private String category = "";
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        private String description = "";
        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "authors")
        @XmlElement(name = "author")
        private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();

        public Book() {}

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public void setCategory(String category) {
            this.category = category;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public void setAuthors(Author author) {
            authors.add(author);
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getCategory() {
            return category;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public List<Author> getAuthor() {
            return authors;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Книга №" + getId() + ": " + '\"' + getTitle() + '\"' + ", авторы - " + getAuthor() + ", категория - " +
                    getCategory() + ", серия - " + getDescription();
        }

        public int compareToAuthors(Book b) {
            return this.getAuthor().get(0).compareTo(b.getAuthor().get(0));
        }

        public int compareToBookName(Book b) {
            return this.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }

        public boolean isBookNull() {
            return (this.getId() == null || this.getId().equals("") &&
                    this.getTitle() == null || this.getTitle().equals("") &&
                    this.getCategory() == null || this.getCategory().equals("") &&
                    this.getDescription() == null || this.getDescription().equals("") &&
                    this.isListAuthorsEmpty());
        }

        private boolean isListAuthorsEmpty() {
            for (Author a : this.getAuthor()) {
                if (a.isAuthorAbsence()) this.getAuthor().remove(a);
            }
            return this.getAuthor().size() == 0;
        }
    }
```

Класс Author:

```
@XmlType(name = "author")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Author {

        @XmlValue
        private String name;

        public Author() {}

        public Author(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

        public int compareTo(Author author) {
            return this.name.compareTo(author.name);
        }

        public boolean isAuthorAbsence() {
            return this.getName() == null || this.equals("");
        }
    }
```

Сообственно, парсер:

```
@Override
public void parsingFile(String filePath, String fileName) {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Books.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath + fileName);
        Books books = (Books) um.unmarshal(reader);
    } catch (UnmarshalException ue) {
        ue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

А вот текст ошибки:

```
    javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at by.zarudniy.alexander.parsers.JAXBParserBook.parsingFile(JAXBParserBook.java:28)
    at by.zarudniy.alexander.parsers.ParserBook.<init>(ParserBook.java:11)
    at by.zarudniy.alexander.parsers.JAXBParserBook.<init>(JAXBParserBook.java:14)
    at JAXBTest.testAllFieldsEmpty(JAXBTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:994)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Вы привели пример нормальной XML. Приведите пример той, которая ломается

Comment: Ломается именно эта, последний тег <book> содержит только пустые поля, я думаю поэтому.

Comment: Приведите пож. текст ошибки + код, как вы демаршализируете в класс `Books`. Потому, что я только что попробовал и у меня нормально все отработало с даными классами и приведенной XML

Comment: попробовал с вашим парсером. Работает. Может проблема из-за каких либо символов, специфичных для ОС. У вас что? Проверял я на бубунте

Comment: Проверьте содержимое файлов. Точно там они не битые? Т.е. вот я, к примеру, получал такое исключение, когда копировал ваш пример в файл XML и не всё скопировал

Comment: Этот же файл тестировал с помощью SAX и DOM - и всё нормально

Comment: путь к файлу тот же, верно? Судя по ошибке в файле содержится некорректная XML. Теги побиты или ещё что-то. К примеру пробел или невидимый символ в первой строке на 1 позиции

Comment: Вы были правы, это была проблема с файлом, хоть я и не понял, какая. Я просто заново создал файл с такими же полями и тегами - и всё распарсилось

Comment: )) Отлично. Поздравляю

Comment: Вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog зарубежные братья дают ответ по Вашей ошибке.

Comment: Любопытно, что новый валидный файл с аналогичным содержимым отличается от старого на 3 байта )))